# Oracle SQL Developer prompting for Radius 2FA authentication twice

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad, radius

I recently switched to Radius 2FA for my Oracle database. When I tried to connect to the database using my Radius pin on Oracle SQL Developer, I get prompted twice for authentication before my connection is established.

This same issue is happening when I use Toad Data Point to connect to the same database. The only difference is that my connection is established upon the 1st authentication prompt. The 2nd authentication prompt doesn't affect the connection.

Has anyone encountered this before? I am using SQL Developer version 4.1.3.20 and Toad Data Point version 4.3.0.718.

---

**Update 15 Mar**

It looks like the 2 times authentication is because of this, where a 2nd connection is established for code insights.
https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/10/unshared-worksheets-in-oracle-sql-developer-4/

Is there anywhere to disable the code insights for SQL Developer to test out the assumption?

Comment: SQL developer is on version 21.  Maybe time for an upgrade?

Comment: I have a colleague who is on version 21 and also facing this issue. Do you know if certain versions of SQL Developer can cause this?